# Get X.509 Certificate ECDH private and public key on Android (Java/Kotlin)

Tags: encryption, kotlin, cryptography, certificate, diffie-hellman

I'm currently trying to implement a ECDH algorithm in my android app.
But I'm facing an issue, I would like to store the private and public key in Android KeyStore. However in order to achieve this I need to get a certificate for my keyPair. And that's where I'm stuck.

I cannot get a correct Certificate which will be allowed by Android KeyStore to be used.

Here is how I generate the key (stripped down version)

```
    val ecParamSpec = ECGenParameterSpec("secp521r1")
    val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC")
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecParamSpec, SecureRandom())

    val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

    val privateKey = keyPair.private
    val publicKey = keyPair.public
```

And for the Certificate I tried this (used SHA256WithECDSA)

```
    val startDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    val endDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        add(Calendar.YEAR, 20)
    }
    val certBuilder = X509v3CertificateBuilder(
        X500Name("CN=MASTERKEY CA Certificate"),
        BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),
        startDate.time,
        endDate.time,
        X500Name("DN=MASTERKEY CA Certificate"),
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.public.encoded)
    )
    val builder = JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithECDSA")
    val signer = builder.build(keyPair.private)
    val certBytes = certBuilder.build(signer).encoded
    val certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")

    val certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes)) as X509Certificate
```

And this is easily understandable that this won't work since the JcaContentSignerBuilder algorithm isn't the same as the KeyPairGenerator. And that's where Android KeyStore start telling me something is wrong.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: private key algorithm does not match algorithm of public key in end entity certificate (at index 0)
```

I used this code to try to store the key in the Android KeyStore

```
keyStore.setEntry("MASTERKEY", KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(key[DH.PRIVATE_KEY] as PrivateKey, arrayOf(key[DH.CERTIFICATE] as Certificate)),
                        KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN).setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                            .build())
```

I'm using **spongycastle** in case you're asking.

If anyone is able to help me, I'll be very grateful ! 
Thanks all.

Comment: Could you try specifying `"EC"` or even `"ECDSA"` for the key pair generator? Because those keys are identical *but for* the algorithm spec. Then you can get the private key and hopefully it will still work for your key agreement. You could also create a two cert chain where you create a ECDH certificate and sign it with a self signed ECDSA based certificate, but that seems more work, and I don't know if ECDH based certs are supported by the cert builder.

Comment: Key(pair) type EC usable for both algorithms ECDSA and ECDH is definitely correct for _BouncyCastle_ (as well as SunEC) in JavaSE. Normally it's best practice for ECDH cert to have KeyUsage extension set to permit keyAgree and prohibit digSign, but if you're never sharing this cert it doesn't matter. A selfsigned cert _should_ have issuer=subject, but you've used CN (which is common) in one and DN (which is different and exceedingly rare) in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the way I worked around this problem is by saving the encrypted private key in sharedpref. I know it's not the best but I've encrypted it using an AES key which is handled by the Android Key Store. Unless AES is cracked, there is no way to decrypt this without the key.

Comment: Beware that just using AES - the block cipher - doesn't mean that the entire solution is secure, per se. There can be issues with the implementation of AES on the platform or the protocol that you've devised may not be secure. I'm not saying that it is, but the common "AES thus secure" argument doesn't necessarily hold and often doesn't hold.